# Persistent Database Connections and mysql_insert_id()

Tags: php, mysql, database

**Description :**

I have an SQL query that inserts the data into the table (I AM USING MYSQL)
Then I have another sql query that inserts data into another table with an id of the data inserted before it... I achieved it couple of months ago using a very rookie method like this

```
if(mysqli_query($con,
    "INSERT INTO  `plumit`.`posts` (
        `posted_on_id`,
        `poster_id`,
        `post_type` ,
        `post` ,
        `likes` ,
        `dislikes` ,
        `comments` ,
        `post_date`
    ) VALUES (
        '$posted_on_id', 
        '$reg_no', 
        'text',  
        '$data',  
        '0',  
        '0',  
        '', 
        '$datetime'
    )")
 ){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,
        "select * from posts order by post_id desc limit 1"
    );
    while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH))
    {
        $post_id = $rows[0];
    }
    if(mysqli_query("insert into another table using $post_id"))
    {
        echo "Success";
    }
}
```

now I am changing all my code because right now I am making too much requests to the server for queries and have started to learn how to optimize the code and use smarter ways of quering the database...

In order to get the last inserted id I used `mysql_insert_id()` instead of using the select statement
but that returned me nothing but 0.

So after a lot of searching I found out that I have to create persistent database connections in order to make it work So I included this in my php file I am using to insert data

```
$cfg['PersistentConnections'] = TRUE;
```

but that didn't work either if you Google it there are many links that say that creating persistent connections is a very bad idea etc...

All I want is to get the id of the row I inserted not last inserted row because if I get the ID of the last inserted row it can be the id of a different row lets say while i am getting the last id some one else inserts the data so it'll get the id of that row which is wrong ... there will 1000 of users inserting the data and I want the id of the row I just inserted and I have no idea what to do now ?? Any body ?

Comment: in the body of if() where the first query of data insert runs

Comment: mysqli_insert_id() did the job ... now can you tell me if its the best way to do it .... performance wise

Comment: yes, this is the best way. The ID is transferred to the client together with the result of the query and just needs to be asked for - before sending the next query.